# Sysdate vs Timestamp for comparisons

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm checking for product updates that are dependent on time of day - alerting if a product has not updated in the last 2 hours , e.g.:

03:30 - 07:29 we expect only product x to be updating;
07:30 - 11:29 we expect both product x and y to be updating
11:30 - 15:30 we expect only product y to be updating

But we need to be sensitive to products that have not updated *yesterday* and still have not updated *today*. Thus my question - when doing the below timestamp comparisons for product y, I suspect that date is not factored in and therefore a product that hadn't updated potentially gets ignored.

```
(...)
AND inv.timestamp      < sysdate        - (120 / 1440) --older than two hours
AND inv.timestamp      > TRUNC(sysdate) + (690/1440)   --after 11:30
AND inv.timestamp      < TRUNC(sysdate) + (930/1440)   --before 15:30
(...)
```

inv.timestamp is a column in timestamp(6) type. Does trunc(sysdate) implicitly include the present date for comparison or is it only using the time?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I read it as does `trunc(sysdate)` - `sysdate` being 09/03/2012 include 09/03/2012 00:00:00, in which case the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNC(SYSDATE)` returns 00:00:00 of the current day.

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)
-------------------
2012-03-09 00:00:00
```

[Documentation on `TRUNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151)

Answer (score 0):

As eaolson and Ben have already noted, SYSDATE includes the date AND time.  Using TRUNC "removes" the time element, i.e. resets it to midnight of that day.

You may want to consider using the INTERVAL functionality provided by Oracle, to make it clearer what the SQL is doing, e.g.

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(sysdate) + interval '11' hour + interval '30' minute,'dd/mm/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') sysdate_trunced_to_1130,
       to_char(trunc(current_timestamp) + interval '11' hour + interval '30' minute,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') timestamp_trunced_to_1130
FROM dual;
```

Glancing at the code, "(690/1440)" doesn't immediately suggest 11:30 in the morning, but + interval '11' hour + interval '30' minute hopefully is a little better.